# Broadcast receiver doesn't work after moving code to another project

Tags: android

I've looked through the entire code and everything seems to work normally, there are no errors so that makes it even more difficult to find the solution.

I've moved my code to another project.

Here is my broadcast receiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("Next"));
    builder.setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("String"));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(325, builder.build());
}
}
```

I call it in my main activity like so:

```
    private void notifyUser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Next", getResources().getString(R.string.lesson_next));

    int days_int = (sun) ? 1:2;

    for (int i = 0; i < days_length; i++) {
        Calendar[] calendars = getCalendars(i, days_int + i);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = schedules.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < calendars.length; j++) {
            String s = arrayList.get(j);
            if (!s.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.lesson_window))) {
                intent.putExtra("String", s);
                notifyUserTag(intent, 135124 + count, calendars[j].getTimeInMillis());
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void notifyUserTag(Intent intent, int id, long currentTimeMillis) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTimeMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
}

private Calendar[] getCalendars(int i, int day) {
    int[] nums = lessonNum(schedules.get(i)); int len = nums.length;
    Calendar[] calendars = new Calendar[len];
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
        calendars[k] = setCalendar(nums[k], day);
    return calendars;
}

private int[] lessonNum(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList) {
    int size = stringArrayList.size();
    int[] nums = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        nums[i] = lessonNumTry(i, stringArrayList);
    return nums;
}

private int lessonNumTry(int i, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    try {
        if (Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(i).substring(1,2)) == 0)
            return 10;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(i).substring(0,1));
    }
    return -1;
}

private Calendar setCalendar(int i, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 6, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 7, 0);
            break;
        case 2:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 8, 0);
            break;
        case 3:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 8, 55);
            break;
        case 4:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 9, 50);
            break;
        case 5:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 10, 55);
            break;
        case 6:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 11, 50);
            break;
        case 7:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 12, 45);
            break;
        case 8:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 13, 40);
            break;
        case 9:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 14, 25);
            break;
        case 10:
            calHelper(calendar, day, 15, 15);
            break;
    }
    return calendar;
}

private void calHelper(Calendar calendar, int day, int hour, int minute) {
    long currTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long getTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if (getTime < currTime)
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(getTime + 604800000);
}
```

The function that sends the notification (notifyUser()) is supposed to get a set of Calendars each specifying a day/hour/minute and set the alarm to launch the broadcast receiver weekly at that time. I used the exact same code in my old project and it worked, right now it does not. The main change between my old project and the new is that the new is using a Database to store data (sqlite3) whereas the old one used files, I don't think that this is correlated to the fact that the broadcast receiver isn't being called/shown/whatever's going on here.

In the manifest I have this

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: I did now and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if you state in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

the MyBroadcastReceiver must be in the code root, and not in a sub-package. Is it in the root package? You might wanna type out the whole package name in your manifest to be sure, fore example:

```
<receiver android:name="org.myapp.receivers.MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

Comment: It's in the same directory as all the other Java files.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't started intent in notifyUser() method use `sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: Where do I add this line?

Comment: my bad, try to change this line ` AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); ` to  ` AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); `

Comment: Still doesn't work. Although interestingly enough sendBroadcast does in fact send it, so I know that the BroadcastReceiver is working

Comment: Can you log and confirm notifyUserTag() method is being called

Comment: It is being called. Can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You missed sending the broadcast intent after defining the intent. Add this line after defining your intent:

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

register receiver with below intent filter in manifest.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```